# Multiple Ranges with .cells property error

Tags: vba, excel

So I have the below code to select 2 ranges using the cells property as the values of the variables change based on a Combobox Selection:

```
    var1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.ListIndex
    var2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2.ListIndex

    Dim oRange As Range
    Set oRange = Union(Worksheets("Graphs").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(20, 1)), Worksheets("Graphs").Range(Cells(1, var1), Cells(20, var2)))

ORange.Value = "Test"
```

When I run the above code with the "Graphs" sheet as active, it runs smoothly without any errors, however when I run it from "Sheet1" I get the Run-time 1004 'Application-defined or object-defined' error.

I do not want to use the `Worksheets("Graphs").Activate` line as I don't want it to jump between sheets while executing the code.

I would appreciate if someone can kindly clarify why the code fails when running it from another sheet as opposed to running it with the "Graphs" sheet active.

I am open to a workaround in selecting the 2 ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is wrong: Set oRange = Union(Worksheets("Graphs").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(20, 1)), Worksheets("Graphs").Range(Cells(1, var1), Cells(20, var2)))

You haven't said which sheet Cells(1, 1) belongs to. It assumes the active sheet. But it is within a reference to the graphs sheet (which is not active). That is probably the cause of the error.

Comment: Yup, how did this slip past me :( `Set oRange = Union(Worksheets("Graphs").Range(Worksheets("Graphs").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Graphs").Cells(20, 1)), Worksheets("Graphs").Range(Worksheets("Graphs").Cells(var1, 4), Worksheets("Graphs").Cells(var2, 6)))` works fine.